# Getting and using values obtained from multiple text boxes via JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the values from multiple textboxes using JQuery.

I'm a bit of a newbie with Javascript in general. I have a form with the following input element:

```
<input name="milkman" value="jessie"/>
<input name="letterman2" value="jim" />
<input name="newmilk" />
```

I get the values of the first two input elements using:

```
var test_arr = $("input[name*='man']").val();
```

How do I get at the individual textbox values? When I use the alert() function to echo the value of `test_arr`, all I see is the first element's value.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your sample is only returning the value in the first item in the array.  You need to iterate through the array, and you can use the `each`.  The jQuery selector syntax returns a jQuery object that contains matched objects as an array.

You can use the other variation of `$.each`, too, like so...

```
var test_arr = $("input[name*='man']");
$.each(test_arr, function(i, item) {  //i=index, item=element in array
    alert($(item).val());
});
```

Since the jQuery object that's returned is an array of matched elements, you can also use a traditional for loop...

```
//you can also use a traditional for loop
for(var i=0;i<test_arr.length;i++) {
    alert($(test_arr[i]).val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [**each**](http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_139/article_240-jquery-each-loop-example.htm) clause:

```
var test_arr = $("input[name*='man']").each(function() { var current = $(this).val(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the map function.

```
function getAllData(){
  var allData = $("input[name='name_of_the_textbox']").map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  alert(allData);
}
```